# Why won't some MP4 files play via HTML5?

Tags: html, video, html5-video

It's strange, some MP4 files will play in HTML5, but others won't. Here is a test page http://psdtucss.com/test/test2.html, open it in Chrome 19.0.1084.46 m. The first MP4 plays, but the other one won't. What's the reason. The code is very simple:

```
<h3>the first mp4 file can play</h3> 
<p><video width="640" height="264" controls="controls"><source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag.</video></p> 
<h3>but the other can't play</h3> 
<p><video width="640" height="264" controls="controls"><source src="2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag.</video></p>
```

How can I fix this?

I tried videojs, but still some MP4 files won't play. Test page is here:
http://psdtucss.com/test/test.html

Answer (score 19):

mp4 is only the *container* format. It may contain video and audio in a number of different *codecs*. Players (including those in a browser) need to support the container format and all of the used codecs in order to play a video properly.

Using VideoJS is definitely a good idea, it handles a lot of browser-specific workarounds for you.

---

However it does not solve one problem: There is no single video codec supported in all browsers. (See also [Wikipedia: HTML5 video: Browser_support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support))

The practical solution probably is to **provide two versions**: h264 in a mp4 container and what is usually called webm (VP8 video and vorbis audio in a specific Matroska container). With those two you cover all major browsers.

---

For video conversion/recoding there are some tools and services available. I have no idea about your operating system or requirements. So just as a wild guess:

Something I used to help a friend publish *a few* videos on his little blog is [this shell script using ffmpeg](https://gist.github.com/3154378) for conversion. It still leaves a lot of potential for improvement (in all of video quality, performance and coding) but should be good enough to get started.

Comment: Is frame rate ever an issue? I'm working with multiple MP4s where two don't work and they have a frame rate of 29.97. One does work and it has a frame rate of 30fps. They all have the same H.264 codec.

Answer (score 12):

The first video uses h264 encoding which is supported by everything except Firefox and Opera.  The second video uses the MPEG-4 video codec which is not supported by browsers.  The only widely supported video codecs are Theora, H.264 and VP8.

[MPEG-4 Part 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_2) video codec is different from the [MPEG-4 Part 14](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14) container format

Comment: Thanks. BTW, vlc->Tools > Codec Information can find out the codec  , https://success.powerdms.com/s/article/How-can-I-tell-if-my-MP4-video-has-h264-codec?language=en_US

Answer (score 9):

Your video 1.mp4 is encoded using h.264 but video 2.mp4 is not.
get MediaInfo to check about it.

Answer (score 3):

MP4 supports multiple codecs.  Some players don't support all codecs (some codes require licensing, or some codecs were released after the browser was written).

Comment: @FrankLv yes ffmpeg / gstreamer are two good places to start converting video.