# Can't show static loaded videos by Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, video

I'm serving some static HTML, CSS and JS files and also a folder called tmp with some images and video files using Express.js for my Node app:

```
app.use(express.static("build"));

app.use(express.static("../tmp"));
```

When I go to `http://localhost:3003`, it loads up my app very nicely and it loads all the images on my webpage(located in the tmp folder) but the problem is every video file looks like this:

[image]

If I press fullscreen on the video player or even visit the url directly `http://localhost:3003/video_1.mp4`, it works.

Is this a problem with Express.js trying to stream the video data from the tmp folder? I really don't know how to solve this issue. I tried to delay the playback and use a 3rd party library to play the video but no luck.

Comment: Given the fact your video is effectively acquired by the client, this will most likely be an error with the video player itself.

Comment: Strange, im just using a native <video /> element. Shouldn't that work?

Comment: There is some litterature on the Internet about some .mp4 files not working with the html5 video tag. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588654/why-wont-some-mp4-files-play-via-html5) is some, on StackOveflow.

Comment: Seems to work when I directly specify the whole path http://localhost:3003/picture.png in src of the video element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work when I directly specify the whole path localhost:3003/picture.png in src of the video element